# IntelliJ Run Terminal Disappeared

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I opened a Java class with a main method in my project in IntelliJ. I can right-click the main pane and select "run". I am used to some run-terminal opening in the lower half of the IDE. However, nothing happens.

Similarly, there is no run-menu in the tool window. When I try to add it via View → Tool Windows, it is grayed out (see screenshot).

[image]

Comment: That *usually* implies that whatever context you're in, you can't run the file you're looking at.  How are you building this out?  Are you sure it runs if you click on the arrow in the gutter next to main?

Comment: I am pretty sure nothing runs when I click it...

Comment: Show a picture of the file you're trying to run (and this will be one of the very, very few times that a picture is useful on SO).  Not too much, just the parts that indicate where you're attempting to run.

Comment: Hi, I can assure you that the syntax is proper. In fact, I have multiple runnable files in my project that used to work. Currently, I cannot run any. The problem persists after restarting IntelliJ.

Comment: @Janothan Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the sample project and [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Answer (score 0):

In project view check if Intelij recognized your class as class. It should have a blue C icon with a small green run button in the top right corner.

If it did not recognize it correctly try creating a new class by right clicking on your package and creating a new Java class, then copy-paste your code into it, make sure you name the class the same as it was originally.

Comment: It does have the blue C with the green "run" symbol.

Comment: Did you select the Project SDK and Project language level ?

Comment: This may happen if JDK got upgraded under you.

Comment: In the module settings, the JDK and language level are set. It rather feels like IntelliJ has some internal issues. Is there an elegant way to "rebuild" it internally in IntelliJ or do I have to delete the .idea folder and import it as a new project?

Comment: I tried File → Invalidate Caches/Restart... With no effect, however.